# Why I am getting multiple responses from salt-minions?

Tags: node.js, saltstack

I got the first response of all minions in valid json string but then I am getting three another different responses from same minions which are invalid json strings.

```
root@localhost:/home/i-kod/Desktop/ass1# salt --out json --static '*' test.ping 
{
    "Pavilion": true, 
    "I-Kod": true
}
{
    "Pavilion": true
}
{
    "I-Kod": true
}
{
    "neha-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC": "Minion did not return. [Not connected]"
}
root@localhost:/home/i-kod/Desktop/ass1# 

My version information:
root@localhost:/home/i-kod/Desktop/ass1# salt '*' test.versions_report
Pavilion:
               Salt: 0.17.5
             Python: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
             Jinja2: 2.7.2
           M2Crypto: 0.21.1
     msgpack-python: 0.3.0
       msgpack-pure: Not Installed
           pycrypto: 2.6.1
             PyYAML: 3.10
              PyZMQ: 14.0.1
                ZMQ: 4.0.4
I-Kod:
                      Salt: 2015.5.0
                    Python: 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21)
                    Jinja2: 2.7.3
                  M2Crypto: 0.21.1
            msgpack-python: 0.4.2
              msgpack-pure: Not Installed
                  pycrypto: 2.6.1
                   libnacl: Not Installed
                    PyYAML: 3.11
                     ioflo: Not Installed
                     PyZMQ: 14.4.1
                      RAET: Not Installed
                       ZMQ: 4.0.5
                      Mako: 1.0.0
     Debian source package: 2015.5.0+ds-1utopic1
neha-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:
    Minion did not return. [Not connected]
root@localhost:/home/i-kod/Desktop/ass1#
```

I just want valid json string.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have more than one minion process running. `/etc/init.d/salt-minion stop` and `pgrep salt-minion` should return nothing.